# How will do dynamically select the reports if have more than one report in report designer?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Actually In my report contains three table reports.

So when user want to see first table report then remaining two table reports are invisible.

and again ,

user want to see second table report then remaining two table reports are invisible

How will i go through resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the table, then select 'Visibility' tab. There you can set an expression which will allow you to show or hide the table based on the criteria you choose. You also may need to add a parameter which will be used to determine if the table should be visible or not.

Either that or add page breaks after each table (it is also available in table properties), it will place each table on separate page.